# MongoDB Java: How can I represent $in query in DBObject?

Tags: java, mongodb

My schema looks like

```
Id:
date_created:
vars: {
      NAME:
      VALUE:
      EDITABLE:
      .....

}
```

I know that using `command-line` we can select range of documents like

```
.find({'Id': {$in: ['a', 'b', ...]}})
```

Is it possible to do something similar using [DBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/com/mongodb/DBObject.html)?

This is because I want to perform **update** on multiple documents, which have `Id` **in** `a', 'b',' 'c', ...`

Answer (score 0):

Just found http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/com/mongodb/QueryBuilder.html#in(java.lang.Object)